# How to use if statement in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
 Select Value1,Value2,Value3 from Table1 where time > DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE())

 ordery BY time desc
```

Result :

```
Value1=25

Value2=50

Value3=70
```

How can I change result to be

```
Value1=25

Value2=0 (if Value2=50 it will be 0)

Value3=70
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `CASE` statement,

```
SELECT Value1,
       CASE WHEN Value2 = 50 THEN 0 ELSE Value2 END Value2,
       .....
```

Comment: @ 今 草 顿 웃  Executing query time : 00:00:04 for using my first query.  But when I used this query Executing query time : 00:01:04.Is it normal ?

Comment: Mehmet your query is now having to evaluate data in the column `value2` to determine which value to output from the `CASE` statement. So it's going to require further processing, causing execution time to increase.